# Deploy Next.js project on Vercel errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, deployment, vercel

Allways in different projects I can not deploy them and get errors.

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'debug' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/follow-redirects'
```

But i dont have and dont use 'debug'.

And:

```
PrismaClientInitializationError: 
Invalid `prisma.quiz.findMany()` invocation:
Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`5432`
Please make sure your database server is running at `localhost`:`5432`.
at zr.handleRequestError (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:8581)
at zr.handleAndLogRequestError (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:7697)
at zr.request (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:7307)
at async getTopQuizzes (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/424.js:103:21)
at async Home (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:505:24) {
clientVersion: '5.0.0',
errorCode: undefined
}
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: 
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
PrismaClientInitializationError: 
Invalid `prisma.quiz.findMany()` invocation:
Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`5432`
Please make sure your database server is running at `localhost`:`5432`.
at zr.handleRequestError (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:8581)
at zr.handleAndLogRequestError (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:7697)
at zr.request (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:7307)
at async getTopQuizzes (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/424.js:103:21)
at async Home (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:505:24)
```